# Aliasing Strongly Type Model Properties in Angular 7

Tags: typescript, angular7, alias

I have one requirement wherein, i need to display key-value pair collection in the html template, however i need to display some **alias** of the key instead of the actual property name itself, which i declared in my strongly typed model.

so do we have anything like following in Angular 7 as well, like we do have in other languages like C#,JAVA

```
export interface SomeBasicModel {

    [DisplayName('First Name')]  // In C# we have display name as decorator
    firstName : stirng;

    @DisplayName('Last Name')  // or Something like this
    lastName : string;

    @alias('Primary Address') // or Something like this
    address : string;
}
```

so with the example above, i want to display "First Name" instead of "firstName" in my html, and corresponding value against it (read from server).

```
  <div *ngFor="let item of myModel| keyvalue">
      {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
    </div>
```

Now, with above approach i can change only in 1 model file, what alias name i want for my model property, and this will reflect in all of my files, no need to change everywhere.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are decorators: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html take a look

Comment: Thanks @Ric, i saw this, however, writing all the custom code along with my business, just to reflect-metadata, doesn't seem convincing, i was looking if any attribute/ annotations already present. Since Alias is a generic and most often used thing, if this is not available then i am not sure why we don't have handy in Angular 8 as of now